# Homotopic equivalence $\iff$ Covering map?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

What is the relation between the concepts of homotopic equivalent mappings and covering map.

More precisely,

> A continuous map $f:X \to Y$ is an homotopic equivalence $\iff \exists
> g:Y \to X$ continuous such that $g \circ f = Id \land f \circ g = Id$.
>
> A covering of a space $X$  is $(\hat X,\pi)$ where $\pi:\hat X \to X$
>   is continuous, surjective and verifies that for each point $x \in X$
>   there exists an open, path-connected neighborhood set $U$ such that the
>   path-connected components of $\pi^{-1}(U)$ are homeomorphic to $U$.

My question is:

*If $f$ is homotopic equivalence we would have $(X,f)$ covering of $Y$? Reciprocally, if $(\hat X,\pi)$ is a covering then $\pi$ is an homotopic equivalence?*

Comment: No to both.  For the second, $\mathbb{R}$ is not even close to homotopy equivalent to the circle.

Comment: Sure.  The real line and a point are homotopy equivalent by a constant map.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure you can prove that homotopy theory would have been dead in 1945 if this were a true equivalence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first is false.  The real line is contractible, so there is a homotopy equivalence $\mathbb{R} \to \{0\}$.  This cannot be a cover because the fiber isn't discrete.

The second is also false.  The universal cover $\mathrm{exp:} \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ is not even close to a homotopy equivalence.